# Will Spring Roo 2 support MongoDB?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

According with the [Spring Roo 1.3 Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/base-layers.html#d4e2012), MongoDB is supported, and can be configured with:

```
roo> mongo setup
```

But with Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 you get:

```
roo> mongo setup
Command 'mongo setup' not found (for assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
Searching 'mongo setup' on installed repositories
0 matches found with 'mongo setup' on installed repositories
```

MongoDB persistence layer was removed? Can be added in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this task](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3596), during the Spring Roo 2.0 definition, we decided to create a smaller and easier to maintain Spring Roo distribution.

From 2.0, Roo will contain the runtime and the main addons only, so new versions could be released more frequently and being kept up to date with lastest Spring projects. This provide us the posibility of make a better separation between the Spring Roo runtime and the main addons. The Roo runtime APIs (classpath, metadata, support, etc.) must be kept as stable and backwards compatible as possible.

On the other hand, we moved the addons not classified as ”main addon” (GWT, JSF, Mongo DB ...) to their own Git repository

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo-community-addons

These addons will be maintained by the Roo community.

From now on we will know this addons as “Spring Roo Community Addons”.

As you could see, these addons are not migrated to the Spring Roo 2.x version, so if you want to use the Mongo DB addon you should download from there and apply some updates. After apply changes, generate the `.jar` files and use the `addon install` commands to include them in the Spring Roo shell.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Ok @jcgarcia, I have to say I very disappointed of this, in a word getting more “NoSQL”, this is like an important downgrade of the product, but I understand that it's difficult to seek funds to maintain a project like this, and some times you need to focus in your customer's needs. I cannot found any guide of how to develop and publish an addon for Spring Roo 2. Is there a guide for that?

Comment: Hi @Mrdev, it was a difficult decission but, as you said, we prefered to focus our efforts in generate complete and advanced Spring applications instead of provide a lot of different functionalities that doesn't works in a production environment. The spring-roo addons are maven modules that you coukd compile individually. After that, you could install them using the `addon install` command. Anyway, I'll try to find some guide about addon development. Regards,

Comment: Hi @jcgarcia i was trying to install the layers repository mongo, but didnt find a way.. was trying to build it and install it as script - failed, tried to use addon install url -url - same thing, could you share the needed command to install mongodb in spring roo? thanks!